# How Do I Securely Edit a Database Entry Based On ID in an Admin System?

Tags: web-development, security, django

This is more of a conceptual question because the way that I am doing it would be secure enough for my purposes (educational). I created a simple admin panel that displays a stock picks database as inputs:

```
{% for pick in picks %}
        <tr data-post-id="{{i.id}}">
            <td class="symbol"><input type="text" value="{{pick.symbol}}"></td>
            <td class="buy_date"><input type="text" value="{{pick.buy_datetime}}"></td>
            <td class="buy_price"><input type="text" value="{{pick.buy_price}}"></td>
            <td class="sell_price"><input type="text" value="{{pick.sell_price}}"></td>
            <td class="quantity"><input type="text" value="{{pick.buy_quantity}}"></td>
            <td class="current_price"><input type="text" value="{{pick.current_price}}" disabled></td>
            <td class="save"><button>save</button></td>
        </tr>
{%endfor%}
```

In the panel, you can edit the individual row and save it to the database through an ajax request based on the data-post-id. Then it dawned on me, if a malicious user was able to bypass the login system, could they edit any row in the table by changing the data-post-id in their browser? If so, what else can I do to limit what can be edited and make sure that only what is intended to be edited is edited?

Answer (score 1):

For casual protection, you can hash some identification fields (including the ID) and include the hash in the page.  When the page is posted, you hash the fields again, and compare them with the hash stored in the page.  Make sure it's a salted hash so that it's difficult for the attacker to recreate the hash algorithm and make their own fake hash.

For better protection, encrypt the ID before rendering it in the page, and decrypt it when the page is POSTed.

**Further Reading**
[Prevent form tampering of hidden fields in Django](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1835/)
[MVC Security Extensions](http://mvcsecurity.codeplex.com/)

Comment: with hashing can't someone just replace the hash of one row with the hash of another row?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: if I am understanding you correctly, you are saying that I should set data-post-id to a hash of the id but if a malicious user swapped the attribute of two table rows, then a malicious user can swap the data of any two rows of a database on submit

Comment: Presumably, a user with sufficient rights in an editing form could do that anyway, by simply swapping the data values in the input controls.

Comment: so if I wanted to swap values in phpmyadmin I could? so it is fine according to security standards?

Comment: What would be the point?  You're talking about two rows in an order invoice.  So you swap two rows... Who cares?

Comment: I know I am just trying to learn if there are any security considerations that I was not aware of. I was thinking of a user somehow getting into a users table and swapping user data (e.g. bank account info)

Comment: That would already be taken care of by encrypting the ID.